# PHP SSH query fails to execute on specific query

Tags: php, ssh

So, i'm using SSH lib and everything works fine with simple ssh queries like:

```
mkdir mydir
```

but when i'm trying to change user password, it doesn't work, i have copied the same query text in putty, there it work fine. I think it's problem with something else.
My user pass code line:

`$ssh->SendCommand('echo -e "'.$new_pw.'\n'.$new_pw.'" | passwd '.$sd[0]['port'].'')`;

Comment: Get an output of your command first. You'll probably see that there is no line-break in there. `\n` in single quotes doesn't work in PHP.

Comment: so what char should i use?

Comment: Adding a line-break with `\n` only works within double quotes. `"\n"` inserts a line break, `'\n'` inserts `\n`.

Comment: could you write this in correct way: $ssh->SendCommand('echo -e "'.$new_pw.'\n'.$new_pw.'" | passwd '.$sd[0]['port'].'');

Comment: Sorry. I just noticed, that I made a false assumption. I'd say that your approach should be working. If it's not doing what you want it to do, it's probably an issue with the way the command is executed on the remote system. As I said in the beginning: Put the command in a variable and log/output it before sending it to the remote server. Also check the message you get back from the server.

Comment: What is this _SSH lib_? What is this function _`SendCommand`_?

Answer (score 1):

Using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html),

```
$ssh->enablePTY(); 
$ssh->exec('passwd');
$ssh->write("newpw\n");
$ssh->read('password:'); // full string is "Retype new UNIX password:"
$ssh->write("newpw\n");
$ssh->read('success'); // full string is "passwd: password updated successfully"
```